# UnsupportedClassVersionError for same major but different minor versions?

Tags: java, unsupported-class-version

I compiled my application with 1.6.xxx. If I try to execute in a lesser 1.6.yyy, will I get an UnsupportedClassVersionError?

Comment: have you tried? I would expect minor versions not to cause backward compability issues, but still ... why are you still on Java 6?

Comment: Please give a concrete example, which means the code you wrote, the compiler you used and the runtime you used. Saying "I used 1.6.xxx" is not concrete enough.

Comment: As far as I know, changes like these have never been introduced between Java update versions in the past, so you would not get an `UnsupportedClassVersionError` when you use a different update version (staying on the same major version).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The minor version has not been set to any value other than zero since Java 1.2, as stated in the [JVM Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se9/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.4):

> Oracle's Java Virtual Machine implementation in JDK release 1.0.2 supports class file format versions 45.0 through 45.3 inclusive. JDK releases 1.1.* support class file format versions in the range 45.0 through 45.65535 inclusive. For k ≥ 2, JDK release 1.k supports class file format versions in the range 45.0 through 44+k.0 inclusive.